# Forecast Error (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, time-series, arima

When I try to run the following code with R:

```
 d.arima=autoplot(vv, ts.colour = ('dodgerblue3'), ts.linetype =  'dashed',
 xlab='Date',ylab='Consommation des pdts pétroliers',
 main="Evolution de la consommation mensuelle des produits pétroliers")
 d.forecast <- forecast(d.arima, level = c(80,95), h = 50)
 autoplot(d.forecast)
```

I get this error :

```
  Error in is.constant(y) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

PS:

```
class(d.arima)
[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

Can anyone give me a hand on solving the problem ?

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `d.arima` is a `ggplot` object, while `forecast` expects an object of class `Arima`. Try `forecast(vv, etc)`.